# Does running a single Nvidia RTX 2080 Ti with X Server on debian impacts performance training Tensorflow models?

Tags: debian, graphics-card, gpu

I have a setup with Ryzen 3700X, Asus Prime B450M-K, and an Nvidia RTX2080 Ti.
The CPU doesn't have abundant PCI-E lanes but for a single PCI-E 3.0 x16 for the card. With that in mind, I refrained from thinking to expand the build without replacing the CPU. But I am wondering if this single GPU setup affects training speed for Tensorflow.

I am skeptical about how CUDA works and if GPU is affected by context switch like CPU. If they do, can I add a new basic (definitely slower than what PCI-E 3.0 x4 can feed) graphic card (with a new motherboard) to fix the performance?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply yes. Using X and CUDA impacts performance. 
 Nvidia has a really old guide about it. The best option would be to use two GPUs but the driver version must support two cards otherwise you won't be use two cards at the same time. Or using without X is also an option.
See: https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x